# Retrieve classifier performance metrics from ROCR prediction object

Tags: r

I use ROCR to get measurements of the performance of various classification algorithms on my dataset. While I can retrieve the AUC metric relatively easily using the following code sample:

```
predictions <- predict(rfmodel, test, type="prob")
pred.obj <- prediction(predictions[,2], data$response)
rfperf <- performance(pred.obj, "tpr","fpr")
print(sprintf("random forest AUC %f", as.numeric(performance(pred.obj,"auc")@y.values)))
```

I have trouble retrieving other retrieving other measures like precision, recall, f etc as a single value that I could include in a table in my paper. I have tried the following:

```
> p <- performance(pred.obj,"prec", "rec")
> as.numeric(p@x.values)
Error: (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'
```

I can plot the values, but this is not what I would like. Any ideas?

Comment: This seems to be a programming question. I will flag it for migration.

Comment: My question also had a statistics component: the ?unlist function will return a vector of answers. What is precision or recall then? The mean of those numbers? The median?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the output is a list. Try 
as.numeric( unlist ( p@x.values) )

Comment: Thanks this seems to be working, for the data extraction part at least

Answer (score 2):

This has to do with the structure of the return object of the function perf. Using str on it will help.

p@x.values is a list, containing one element which is a vector of numerical values.
Just use

```
p@x.values[[1]]
```

to extract the vector.